# GPU issue with multiple Inception V3 trained models

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

While using multiple (three) trained tensorflow models on python run parallelly as 3 threads (or just 2); I get memory outage but no issue on running each individually on each GPU seperately (2X3 = 6 times) or as per code config below.

GPU config -

GeForce GTX 1060 6GB major
totalMemory: 5.93GiB freeMemory: 5.69GiB  memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.7715

GeForce GTX 1050 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.392 =>ignored
totalMemory: 3.94GiB freeMemory: 3.89GiB

Individual Model Files' relevant (GPU related) code-

```
1)d = '/gpu:0'
  config=tf.ConfigProto()
  #config.log_device_placement= True
  print("SUNGLASSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS")
  #config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.3
  config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=tf.GPUOptions(visible_device_list='0'))
  with tf.device(d):
      with tf.Session(graph=graph, config=config) as sess:
        results = sess.run(output_operation.outputs[0], {
            input_operation.outputs[0]: t
        })
  results = np.squeeze(results)

2)
d = '/gpu:1'
  config=tf.ConfigProto()
  #config.log_device_placement= True
  print("HATSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS")
  config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.35
  config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=False,gpu_options=tf.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True),allow_soft_placement = True)
  with tf.Session(graph=graph, config=config) as sess:
    results = sess.run(output_operation.outputs[0], {
        input_operation.outputs[0]: t
    })
  results = np.squeeze(results)

3)
d = '/gpu:1'
  config=tf.ConfigProto()
  #config.log_device_placement= True
  print("HANDSNEARFACEEEEEEEEEEEEE")
  config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.4
  #config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=False,gpu_options=tf.GPUOptions(allow_growth=False),allow_soft_placement = True)
  with tf.device(d):
      with tf.Session(graph=graph, config=config) as sess:
        results = sess.run(output_operation.outputs[0], {
            input_operation.outputs[0]: t
        })
  results = np.squeeze(results)
```

Comment: Can we see error message?